# Select List for Sorting by City

Tags: drupal-7, geolocation, drupal-views

Looking to do something along the lines of how kijiji.ca and redflagdeals.com manages their content based on the location chosen. I'm trying to use the getlocation module but I can't really figure out whether it's the right thing to try. I want the default location to be retrieved automatically through the ip address and then give the users the option to change the city which will corresponding with a change of content..

Just looking for someone to steer me in the right direction as I can't seem to figure this out..thanks!